# Change content on Tablet and Mobile View

Tags: html, css

```css
.img1{
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
.arrow{
    content:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSO3ZJVteOkqFdOVDcy8HlfYwW4LerPJ6HZpsq53KJ9obfRoJPgbg)
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    float:right;
}
.img2{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="img1"></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="img2"></div>
</div>
```

I have a simple site showing illustration of changes. 
Example 
`Image1`→ `Image2`
`Image3`→`Image4`
In desktop view its normal, but on iphone view that `→`arrow , shows up like this 
`Image1`
→
`Image2`
Here I want that arrow to show up as 
`Image1`
↓
`Image2`
I tried by using `@media-screen` with `content:url(aaa.com/aa.jpg)`
But it doesnt show up.
Note:- I am using "elementor pro" page builder to build the site

Comment: Add your HTML & CSS Code here.

Comment: Added html and css, But arrow pic is not showing here. I dont know why.

Comment: Add a semicolor ; after content-url ends in the above snippet, to show the arrow image

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to take the flexbox approach wherein you can simply change the `flex-direction` and rotate the `arrow` icon in the media query

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.img1,
.img2,
.arrow {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.img2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.arrow {
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSO3ZJVteOkqFdOVDcy8HlfYwW4LerPJ6HZpsq53KJ9obfRoJPgbg) no-repeat 0 50%/100%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .arrow {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img1"></div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="img2"></div>
</div>
```